# Dotnet Core 2: How can I enforce project characteristics across multiple projects? Equivalent of a Java/Maven parent POM?

Tags: .net-core

I am primarily a java developer, but I am developing a dotnet core 2 platform of restful services (`webapi`'s).  In Java/Maven, I can have a parent POM that includes all the outside dependencies of the project, enforces unit tests on the build, runs various static code analysis, etc.

Is there any way to do these things in dotnet core 2? Can I have a "parent solution" file that does some of these things?  Is there a dotnet core 2 standard for tying multiple projects together in this sense?  Or do I have to trust that my developers will have the discipline to make sure their projects follow the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can define common elements in a main msbuild file, then [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild) it in your various `.csproj` files.

For example, corefx has a file that lists all dependency versions. This file then gets imported into various other build files: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/dependencies.props